# How to select a root Object3D using Raycaster

Tags: three.js

I have a parent `Object3D` that has child meshes. How can I use `Raycaster` to select only the root parent object?

[my example](http://neftek.legko.ufanet.ru/MyWebGL/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a parent `Object3D` that has multiple child meshes, and you want to select the parent by raycasting, you can do the following:

Add the parent object to the array of objects:

```
var objects = [];
...
objects.push( root_parent_object );
```

Add to each child object a pointer to the root parent object:

```
child.userData.parent = root_parent_object;
```

Pass in the recursive flag to `intersectObjects()`.

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
```

Now when the raycaster intersects a child object, you can obtain the root object.

three.js r.68

Comment: It moves on pieces )). http://neftek.legko.ufanet.ru/MyWebGL/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html. It turned out by means of BoundingBoxHelper

Comment: You need to select the root: `SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object.userData.parent;`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar need using collada objects exported from Sketchup. Meshes have a trail of multiple parents ahead of them so all I did was this:

```
if (intersects.length >0){
    par = intersects[ 0 ].object.parent;
    while(par.type !== "Group"){
        par = par.parent;
    } 
    groupName = par.name;
}
```