# threejs move entire object not just children

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am building a small app in which I want to move objects around. I have used https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html as example and it somewhat works. I load json models but for some reason I can only move parts of the model and not the entire model at once. I suspect it has something to do with the recursive flag on the raycaster. Setting the recursive flag to false results in no movement at all of the object.

Moving simple meshes works like a charm.

Is there anything I am missing?

init.js:

```
// INIT VARS ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var container, camera, clock, renderer, scene, controls, startTime, OrtCamera, PersCamera;
var orthoCam = false;
var objects = []; // Put objects into array so we can use a raycaster with intersect
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var offset = new THREE.Vector3();
var intersection = new THREE.Vector3()
var INTERSECTED, SELECTED;
var object;
var plane = new THREE.Plane();
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
var line;



function init() {
    // CLOCK ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    clock = new THREE.Clock();

    // perspective CAMERA
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 10000);
    camera.position.x = 200;
    camera.position.y = 200;
    camera.position.z = 200;

    camera.position.set(0, 90, 0);
    camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

    // CONTROLS ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, canvas );

    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI/2;
    controls.maxDistance = Infinity;

    // to disable zoom
    controls.enableZoom = true;

    // to disable rotation
    controls.enableRotate = true;

    // to disable pan
    controls.enablePan = true;


    // RENDERER ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    container = document.getElementById( "canvas" );
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: container, antialias: true, alpha:true});
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight - 100);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF, 0);

    // SCENE ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    scene = new THREE.Scene();  

    // LIGHT ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ); // soft white light


    startTime = Date.now();

    // Test object(s) for mouse movement. Can be deleted once done.
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 0.1, 50 );
    object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );
    object2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );
    object.position.y = 0;
    object2.position.y = 5;
    object2.position.z = 70;

    object.castShadow = true;
    object.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( object );
    scene.add( object2 );
    objects.push( object );
    objects.push( object2 );



    // Load 3D model from json file
    loader.load('/resources/models/tree2.json', function(tree){
        var combined = new THREE.Geometry();

        tree.updateMatrix();
        tree.scale.set(5,5,5);
        tree.position.y = 5;        


        scene.add(tree);

        objects.push(tree);

    });

    scene.add( light );

}
/**
 * animate and display the scene
*/
function animate() {
    // render the 3D scene
    render();

    // relaunch the 'timer' 
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

}
/**
 * Render the 3D scene
*/
function render() {

    renderer.render( scene, camera );  

}
```

main.js:

```
/**
 * Add event listeners for drag-and-drop of objects.
*/
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false  );
document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false  );

/**
 * Mouse move event
*/
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    if ( SELECTED ) {
        if ( raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( plane, intersection ) ) {
            SELECTED.position.copy( intersection.sub( offset ) );
        }
        return;
    }
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {
            if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
            INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
            INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
            plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(
                camera.getWorldDirection( plane.normal ),
                INTERSECTED.position );
        }
        container.style.cursor = 'pointer';

    } else {
        if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
        INTERSECTED = null;
        container.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }
}

/**
 * Mouse down event
*/
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        console.log(intersects);
        controls.enabled = false;
        SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
        if ( raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( plane, intersection ) ) {
            offset.copy( intersection ).sub( SELECTED.position );
        }
        container.style.cursor = 'move';
    }
}

/**
 * Mouse up event
*/
function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    controls.enabled = true;
    if ( INTERSECTED ) {
        SELECTED = null;
    }
    container.style.cursor = 'auto';
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202064/how-to-select-a-root-object3d-using-raycaster/26205768#26205768

Comment: You made my day @WestLangley! That did the trick.