# Three.js dragging collada objects breaks them apart

Tags: three.js, blender, drag, collada, 3dsmax

I've followed the excellent example "objects controls" example by alexan030 to import and drag collada objects at http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/controls_events_loaders.html.
However, my own collada objects break apart when dragging.

For example, if my model comprises of three spheres, I can only drag each of the spheres individually. Is this a problem with my .DAE file / original model, or something I need to address in the code?

My models are created using 3DS Max and/or Blender and exported using Open Collada.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202064/how-to-select-a-root-object3d-using-raycaster

Comment: `var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );` stops the drag functionality entirely. Works OK without the "true". Also, I don't know how to specify adding child items when they're objects within the .dae file.